# How to get older versions for clojure data structures

Tags: clojure

Clojure is using persistent data structures , is there a way to access older versions of vector or maps since it is keeping it internally ?

Lets say for a Vector ,what i meant is since clojure is not copying full structure and keeping it in a tree internally (see https://hypirion.com/musings/understanding-persistent-vector-pt-1) and keeps older structure values too, is there a way to use this to do some senarios like undo/redo or replay, It is using the same principle for Datomic to retrieve older version for data, so im asking if it is possible to get this in clojure.

Comment: What do you mean by "older versions of vector"? Objects that you don't hold a reference to?

Comment: You could store a vector in an atom and use `add-watch` to subscribe to changes, in the subscriber `conj` each new state on to a list or vector stored in another atom...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Kris's comment, using add-watch is the right answer it seems ,
David Nolen has described this approach here
https://swannodette.github.io/2013/12/31/time-travel

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I understood the question, but just keep a reference on the old structure.

```
(def my-old-map {a 1, b 2, c 3})
(def my-new-map (assoc my-old-map b 7))
```

Comment: Right, the older versions are not kept around. The unreferenced portions become eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

Any version of a persistent data structure survives so long as there is a live reference to it. Thereafter, it is subject to garbage collection.

The Clojure persistent vectors and maps are like copy-on-write file systems such as [Btrfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs), both in concept and in the sort of internal data structures they employ to create the illusion that each version of an entity is quite distinct.