# How to achieve Time Travel with clojure

Tags: data-structures, clojure, immutability, datomic

Is there a way to achieve time traveling in Clojure, for example if I have a vector (which is internally a tree implemented as a persistent data structure) is there a way to achieve time traveling and get preivous versions of that vector? Kind of what Datomic does at the database level, since Clojure and Datomic share many concepts including the facts being immutable implemented as persistent data strcutures, technically the older version of the vector is still there. So I was wondering if time traveling and getting previous versions is possible in plain Clojure similarly to what it is done in Datomic at the database level

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same question that you asked a couple of days ago?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get older versions for clojure data structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49246341/how-to-get-older-versions-for-clojure-data-structures)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but you need to keep a reference to it in order to access it, and in order to prevent it from being garbage collected. Clojurists often implement undo/redo in this way; all you need to do is maintain a list of historical states of your data, and then you can trivially step backward.

David Nolen has described this approach [here](https://swannodette.github.io/2013/12/31/time-travel), and you can find a more detailed example and explanation [here](https://macwright.org/2016/02/07/undo-redo-clojurescript.html).

Answer (score 0):

Datomic is plain Clojure. You can use Datomic as a Clojure library either with an in-memory database (for version tracking) or with no database at all.